# Error while authenticating an app with linkedin

Tags: c#, oauth, xamarin, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

Im getting the following error while trying to authenticate with LinkedIn.
"Invalid redirect URI"

The link is valid and registered with my app inside the linked in developer site.

What could cause this error?

```
  var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator
  (
     clientId: "MYID",
     scope: "r_basicprofile",
     authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=MYID&redirect_uri=https://wicareerpathways.org/&state=987654321&scope=r_basicprofile"),              
     redirectUrl: new Uri("https://wicareerpathways.org/")
  );
```

Comment: when do you get the error after instantiating a new instance..? have you looked at the LinkedIn api / documentation [LinkedIn Developer Support](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi2-K7pkNzJAhWEVD4KHddQDR8QFggoMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.linkedin.com%2Fsupport&usg=AFQjCNFChuuBYxo9LL8iItRSIIceDhyQtA&sig2=BkGPrWTzomznJlQoOhPj4A&bvm=bv.109910813,d.eWE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something this :

```
var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator (
                clientId: "**",
                clientSecret:"**",
                scope: "r_fullprofile r_contactinfo",
                authorizeUrl: new Uri ("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization"),
                redirectUrl: new Uri ("http://www.***.co.nz/"),
                accessTokenUrl:new Uri("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken")    
            );
```

Refer : 
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/49244/#Comment_49244

Answer (score 0):

Try URL encoding the redirect_url parameter in the authorizeUrl -->

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=MYID&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwicareerpathways.org%2F&state=987654321&scope=r_basicprofile
```

Comment: I tried changing uri to url that and I get a different error that blinks dozens of times. Authentication Error - " you passed ="response_type"+ more+than+once+this+can+only+apear+once."